# using angelscript compile error

Tags: c++, angelscript

I'm trying to use angelscript 2.25.1 using gcc 4.7.1

I compiled angelscript without issues.

When I try to compile my project that uses angelscript, however, I'm getting this error:

```
jarrett@jarrett-g74s:~/projects/myproject$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o build/common/as_wrapper/AngelScript.o -c -I"../lwis/src/engine" -I"../ice_engine/src/engine" src/common/as_wrapper/AngelScript.cpp
src/common/as_wrapper/AngelScript.cpp: In member function ‘void as_wrapper::AngelScript::loadScripts()’:
src/common/as_wrapper/AngelScript.cpp:85:33: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/common/as_wrapper/AngelScript.cpp:87:30: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/common/as_wrapper/AngelScript.cpp:88:31: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
src/common/as_wrapper/AngelScript.cpp: In member function ‘int as_wrapper::AngelScript::initContext(char*, char*)’:
src/common/as_wrapper/AngelScript.cpp:242:20: error: ‘class asIScriptModule’ has no member named ‘GetFunctionIdByDecl’
src/common/as_wrapper/AngelScript.cpp:258:22: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘asIScriptFunction*’ [-fpermissive]
In file included from src/common/as_wrapper/AngelScript.h:11:0,
                                 from src/common/as_wrapper/AngelScript.cpp:8:
/usr/local/include/angelscript/angelscript.h:734:26: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘virtual int asIScriptContext::Prepare(asIScriptFunction*)’ [-fpermissive]
scons: *** [build/common/as_wrapper/AngelScript.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

So basically, it (I guess the compiler) can't find `GetFunctionIdByDecl` function in `asIScriptModule`.  I'm pretty sure it should be there though.

Also, the code on lin 242 is:

```
int funcId = mod->GetFunctionIdByDecl(function);
```

where `function` is declared earlier as a `char*` and `mod` is of type `asIScriptModule *mod`.

I thought this might be an issue with gcc 4.7.1....but I'm not sure.

Comment: According to the source (angelscript.h line 664), `GetFunctionIdByDecl` is deprecated, so you need to `#define AS_DEPRECATED` to use it.

Comment: welp, that did it - I just looked over the api and found the correct way to do it now.  Thanks @chris!  If you put your solution as an Answer I'll mark it as solved (so you get the karma).  Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @chris for the answer.

> According to the source (angelscript.h line 664), GetFunctionIdByDecl
>   is deprecated, so you need to #define AS_DEPRECATED to use it.